# New CSS class won't apply during development

Tags: css, sass, gulp, browser-sync

I am developing a static website in a local environment with gulp, sass, atom as my text editor and an up-to-date Chrome.

For some reason, sometimes when I create a new class, my browser will constantly refuse to recognise it.

Most recent example:

```
.projects {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 10px solid red;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}

.project {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

You can see it in the markup, right there:

[image: DOM view of the code]

If I check my page sources, it's there:

[image: Sources view of the CSS]

The child element, `.project`, is getting its CSS just fine:
[image: project CSS gets there correctly]

But the `.projects` element absolutely refuses to apply its styling:
[image: No styling for me]

### I have tried:

1. Restarting gulp
2. Restarting Chrome
3. Renaming the class (still doesn't work)
4. Applying a different class just to check (applies the styling with no problem)
5. Using it on a different page, same CSS files access (no luck)
6. Mainly, everything works just as expected, but that element in particular will not get any new styles regardless of what I do.

### Full disclaimer

I've been working in this field for years and this just doesn't make sense. I believe the fault might be related to some kind of caching, live reloading with BrowserSync or something like that.

Attached is my `gulpfile.js` as well, if it sheds any light:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/sass/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './app'
    },
  })
})


gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function (){
  gulp.watch('app/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
  // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/about-us/index.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Does the problem persist if you open the page in an incognito window in Chrome?

Comment: @JonUleis yes, it does, and it makes some sense that it does because all pages are linked with BrowserSync. Great question though, I haven't checked that.

Comment: Got it. Another sanity check: in your third screenshot, the context for the CSS is in the top-right as a link (`style.css:506`). If you right click that link and "Open Link in New Tab", are the `.projects` styles visible there, too? (Or is this the file you're showing in your fourth screenshot?)

Comment: @JonUleis yes, they're the declaration above it. That's actually the second screenshot, the view of the compiled CSS file in Sources. Shows up when opening in a new tab as well.

Comment: Oops - I meant second screenshot, not fourth. Okay. Is it possible the rule _above_ `.projects` has an error, like a missing brace, which is causing the rule directly below it to be ignored? Normally Sass won't compile with such an error, but I'm trying to think outside the box. We might end up needing a JSFiddle with your current HTML and entire CSS file.

Comment: Any updates? Still curious about this one.

Comment: @JonUleis there's no error in the SASS or CSS for that matter. Everything is compiled and errors are logged. I've also checked manually and everything seems correct. Here's a quick and dirty JSFiddle, and it seems to be applying the style correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/johnnykb/5moysjq6/

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing any issues in your Fiddle. Truly bizarre.

Comment: I'm really sorry if this is useless, but I didn't read anything where you said you actually cleared Chrome's cache/history/everything (every checkbox checked). You only said you 'restarted it'. I'm not sure if incognito disregards cache, but either way I'd still physically go to Chrome's advanced settings-->Clear Browsing Data, check all checkboxes & clear. Also, make sure Chrome is fully updated. I'd also try working locally from a different computer - perhaps it's OS version related or your machine is kaput. Lastly, try a different browser, if you haven't. Sorry I couldn't offer more.

Comment: At least you have option 4 which works for you. Man...maybe an issue with Gulp, Sass or Flexbox? Try erasing CSS properties/values one at a time from .projects, save and refresh browser each time. You broke my brain :(

Comment: @KyleVassella number 4 is really pointless because it applies different styling that the one I want. Thanks for all your input, but nothing solved it so far. Even tried copying the project to a different computer, removing `node_modules` and doing `npm install` again, still it doesn't work.

Comment: In your Sass function, try ```.pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))```